# Maximizing the area of small rectangles in a bigger one (Rectangle packing)

Tags: algorithm, math, np

Let's say I have a set of rectangles of varying widths and heights, which cannot be rotated.
I now want to fit a subset of those into a larger rectangle with a set height and width, so that the sum of the areas of the smaller rectangles is maximized.

Is there an algorithm that can help me solve this problem?

I tried looking into rectangle packing in general, but all I could find were questions about *minimizing* the area taken up by the rectangles.

Here is a graphical example of what I want to do:

The rectangles on the right are the aforementioned set of smaller rectangles, which I want to fit into the left one.
[image]

As I cannot possibly put all the small rectangles into the bigger one, I now have to choose an optimal subset of them, like this, for example:
[image]

Is this the best arrangement and subset of rectangles? Probably not, since there is still some space left in the bigger rectangle. In an ideal case, the would be exactly 0 space left, and the sum of the areas of the small rectangles would be equal to the area of the big rectangle. However, as this is rarely possible, I need an algorithm, that can find the best possible arrangement and subset.

Comment: This problem is NP-hard.  However a greedy approach of packing from largest to smallest starting in a corner does pretty well in general.

Comment: Thanks! Do you maybe have any links to more resources about this approach?

Comment: To get *good answers*, [ask a *good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - without mention, I assume all rectangles "are parallel"; similarly, `a subset` is the one thing making me *assume* "without overlap": I prefer to be spoon-fed such details explicitly: what exactly is `area taken up by the smaller rectangles`? Does enclosed, uncovered space count against it? Is it the area of the *convex hull*, which as a "parallel rectangle" would be the *bounding box*? There is [en.wikipedia on rectangle packing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Packing_of_rectangles).

Comment: Thanks, I clarified what I meant by the area taken up by the rectangles, and added two pictures illustrating the problem.